# How to Shielding the voice on WebBrowser in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use WebBrowser loading a page, which plays a music, I need not it, how I Shielding the voice

Answer (score 0):

If the web-page is playing a sound, you cannot stop that sound without modifying the target HTML code that invokes it. If it is triggered by a JavaScript call, make sure that you are not setting [IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to **true**.